# checkbox inside span onclick of span.. check input.. jquery recursion problem

Tags: jquery, recursion, click

This code causes a recursive behavior..

I want to be able to click the text in the span and check/uncheck the child input and trigger the click event for the child input.

http://jsfiddle.net/cwfontan/ALEBr/

```
        <span class="RedHover">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkShowBusn" id="chkShowBusn" tabindex="9" />Business
        </span>



$('.RedHover').click(
        function (e) {
            try {
                $(this).children('input').trigger('click');
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('here');
            } catch (e) {
                //handle no click event.alert
                console.log(e.description);
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkShowBusn" id="chkShowBusn" tabindex="9" />
<label for="chkShowBusn">Business</label>
```

And you don't even need jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the event triggered on the `input` element then bubbles up and is handled on the `span`. This happens for the original event and for the event that you fire programmatically.

The solution is probably to check to see if the event originated on an `input` element, and not to handle it if it did:

```
$('.RedHover').click(
    function (e) {
        if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'input') {
            $(this).children('input').trigger('click');
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('here');
        }
    }
);
```

The `try/catch` was unnecessary, jQuery will ensure that the event object always exists and has the methods you use.

The calls to `stopPropgation` and `preventDefault` *may* be unnecessary, depending on your expected behaviour.

---

Since the `span` only has one child, you could do this another way round. If `this` (the element where the event is handled, always the `span`) is the same as `e.target` (the element where the event originated, either the `span` or the `input`), you can proceed:

```
$('.RedHover').click(
    function (e) {
        if (this === e.target) {
            $(this).children('input').trigger('click');
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('here');
        }
    }
);
```

Note that this is much less stable than checking the `nodeName`: if you altered your HTML in future, it may break this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the propagation in the click of the checkbox like so

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
});
```

check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZt2t/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found this to be the solution.

HTML

```
<span for="chkCheckbox">
    <input id="chkCheckbox" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="chkCheckbox">My Checkbox Label</label>
</span>
```

Javascript (expanding to jQuery is easy, I am not including it since it was answered by @lonesomeday, and I always prefer Javascript over using another library)

```
var checkboxSpans = document.querySelectorAll("span[for]");

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxSpans.length; i++) {
    var forCheckbox = checkboxSpans[i].getAttribute("for");
    forCheckbox = document.getElementById(forCheckbox);

    if (forCheckbox != null) {
        checkboxSpans[i].onclick = function (chk) {
            return function (e) {
                if (this === e.target) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (chk.checked != true) {
                        chk.checked = true;
                    } else {
                        chk.checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }(forCheckbox);
    }
}
```

This way you can use it the same as if you would use a label. This can actually be added to any type of element.

This was expanded from the answer provided by @lonesomeday